# PHP split array by matching variable names

Tags: php, arrays, regex, match

This array is being set using the names of files in a given folder. My file names will be in the following format:

```
style1_color1_product1_0000.png
style1_color1_product2_0001.png
style1_color1_product3_0002.png

style1_color2_product1_0003.png
style1_color2_product2_0004.png

style2_color1_product1_0005.png
```

None of the file names will ever be duplicated and there will always be more than one product per style and color.

What I am trying to do is take this array and split it into new arrays based on matching 'style' and 'color' values.

I have gotten as far as opening the file and splitting a new array based on first and second names, but I can't find the answer to grouping into new arrays.

```
$Dir = "products";

$files = scandir($Dir);

array_multisort($files, SORT_STRING);

for ($key = 0, $size = count($files); $key < $size; $key++) {

    if ($files[$key] != '.' && $files[$key] != '..'){

        $new_array[] = explode('_', $files[$key], 3);
    }

}

print_r($new_array);

Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [0] => style1 [1] => color1 [2] => product1_0000.png ) [1] => 
    Array ( [0] => style1 [1] => color1 [2] => product2_0001.png ) [2] => 
    Array ( [0] => style1 [1] => color1 [2] => product2_0002.png ) [3] => )
)


etc
```

Now I need to compare and split with the original array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So do some `foreach` loops. You can even do it in your current `for` loop

Comment: Tip: you must look for SPL function [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) rathar than `scandir` or `glob`

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be made a LOT simpler with a simple regex:

```
$files = glob($Dir."/*.png");
$results = array();
foreach($files as $file) {
    if( preg_match("/style(?<style>\d+)_color(?<color>\d+)_product(?<product>\d+)_(?<id>\d+)\.png/",$file,$match) {
        // you now have $match['style'], $match['color'], $match['product']
        // and $match['id'] for the parts of the filename,
        // and $match[0] for the whole thing
        if( !isset($results[$match['style']])) $results[$match['style']] = array();
        if( !isset($results[$match['style']][$match['color']])) $results[$match['style']][$match['color']] = array();
        $results[$match['style']][$match['color']][$match['product']] = $match['id'];
    }
}
var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solves for you:

```
<?php

$files = array(
    'style1_color1_product1_0000.png',
    'style1_color1_product2_0001.png',
    'style1_color1_product3_0002.png',
    'style1_color2_product1_0003.png',
    'style1_color2_product2_0004.png',
    'style2_color1_product1_0005.png'
);

array_multisort(
    $files,
    SORT_STRING
);

$newArr = array();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $combined = array_combine(
        array(
            'style',
            'color',
            'product'
        ),
        explode(
            '_',
            $file,
            3
        )
    );

    $newArr[$combined['style']][$combined['color']][] = $combined['product'];
}
```

Will result:

```
Array
(
    [style1] => Array
        (
            [color1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product1_0000.png
                    [1] => product2_0001.png
                    [2] => product3_0002.png
                )

            [color2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product1_0003.png
                    [1] => product2_0004.png
                )

        )

    [style2] => Array
        (
            [color1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product1_0005.png
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: That looks like it would be perfect but  $combined = array_combine(['style', 'color', 'product'], explode('_', $file, 3)); produces a syntax error I can't find a work around for.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to add declaring as an array worked. Thank you!